# MoSKito Integration tool RMI Port issue

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am trying to intergrate Moskito inspect monitoring tool with Spring Boot application, however I see issue with rmi port (set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -DlocalRmiRegistryPort=9401) also noticed that after setting the RMIport to 9401, i don't see port is opening (netstat -an | grep 9401)

Here are the steps i have done and getting the error. Please correct me if i am missing anything.

1) My Operating System - Windows 7 
2) I have installed Apache Tomcat v7, Java 8
3) I have downloaded Moskito version 2.7.8 https://www.moskito.org/download.html
4) Installed Moskito inspect and web UI is loading good, where is can see data from the MoSKito Inspect tomcat as mentioned in http://blog.anotheria.net/msk/the-complete-moskito-integration-guide-step-1/
5) I have created a sample Spring Boot web application , built it with "mvn clean package" and created .War file. I see following libraries related to moskito along with other jar files in lib folder.
moskito-aop-2.7.8.jar, moskito-core-2.7.8.jar,moskito-inspect-remote-2.7.8.jar,moskito-web-2.7.8.jar,moskito-webui-2.7.8.jar.
6) When I deploy this war-file , I can access my application by this URL: http://localhost:8090/(port 8090)and application is working good.
6) Now when i configured RMI port 9041 using below command and trying to access moskito-inspect webui by this URLs: http://localhost:8088/moskito, Tomcat response 404 [Not found] with following error message.
Command:

```
java -jar -DlocalRmiRegistryPort=9401 -Dserver.port=8090 myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Error Message:

MoSKito encountered an error:

Cannot connect to localhost@localhost:9401, due: Can not resolve manually set reference. Server at localhost, port: 9401 is down or not properly configured

[net.anotheria.moskito.webui.util.APILookupUtility.findRemote(APILookupUtility.java:203), net.anotheria.moskito.webui.util.APILookupUtility.findRemote(APILookupUtility.java:177), net.anotheria.moskito.webui.util.APILookupUtility.getAdditionalFunctionalityAPI(APILookupUtility.java:130), net.anotheria.moskito.webui.shared.action.BaseMoskitoUIAction.preProcess(BaseMoskitoUIAction.java:404), net.anotheria.maf.MAFFilter.doPerform(MAFFilter.java:260), net.anotheria.maf.MAFFilter.doFilter(MAFFilter.java:215), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208), net.anotheria.anoplass.api.filter.APIFilter.doFilter(APIFilter.java:107), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122), org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171), org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102), org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116), org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408), org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040), org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607), org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617), org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
    <moskito.version>2.7.8</moskito.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
      <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
      <artifactId>moskito-core</artifactId>
      <version>${moskito.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
      <artifactId>moskito-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${moskito.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
  <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
  <artifactId>moskito-inspect-remote</artifactId>
  <version>${moskito.version}</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <configuration>
            <aspectLibraries>
                <aspectLibrary>
                    <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
                    <artifactId>moskito-aop</artifactId>
                </aspectLibrary>
            </aspectLibraries>
            <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What am I doing wrong, may be someone faced the same problem? Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

have you added moskito-springboot dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.anotheria</groupId>
    <artifactId>moskito-springboot</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
</dependency>
```

What it does is starting the backend, but see yourself for details: 
https://github.com/anotheria/moskito/blob/master/moskito-integration/moskito-springboot/src/main/java/net/anotheria/moskito/integration/springboot/MoskitoAutoConfiguration.java

So the magic happens in this call:

```
LOGGER.info("Starting Moskito backend for remote");
StartMoSKitoInspectBackendForRemote.startMoSKitoInspectBackend();
```

You should check the logs for the above message, after you added the artefact.

Hope to help
Leon

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am looking to connect with MoSKito Inspect UI instead Backend for monitoring. I could see that port 9401 is opened when Spring Boot application is launched by using command java -jar -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9401 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.105.52.193 -Dserver.port=8090 target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
However, when i tried to connect from Moskito Inspect UI with localhost: 9401 i still see Cannot connect to 9401

Comment: Appreciate any inputs for above issue i am facing.

Comment: With " -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9401" you open jmx on that port, but you need to open this port for moskito and not jmx. Can you check what other ports are open by this application?

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. Now the issue is resolved after i added WebUI ,Spring-boot dependencies and launched with below command java -jar -DlocalRmiRegistryPort=9401 -Dserver.port=8090 target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar